# How to get value of UnsafeMutableRawPointer?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to get the address that is pointed to by UnsafeMutableRawPointer, but I'm unable to do so. I'm also new to Swift so I might be missing something or doing it completely wrong. Preferably I would like to cast the raw value into a CChar.

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting this pointer from, and where are you trying to use it?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I'm playing around connecting assembly to swift. Trying to understand the mechanics of the unsafe types.

Comment: What does `get the address that is pointed to by UnsafeMutableRawPointer` entail? You want `0x0...0404340` as a value stored in an `Int` or something?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov yes

Comment: What do you want to do with this `Int` that you can't already do (in a safer, more expressive way) with `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I will be calling a routine written in assembly, I need to pass parameters to the routine following the sys v abi. One of those parameters is a void*, hence I need the actual value of UnsafeMutableRawPointer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127974/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-jack-sexton).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note to passers-by: much of my answer won't make sense, as it doesn't answer the initial question above, but rather the question(s) that arose in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127974/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-jack-sexton) with OP.*

Took me a few hours, but now that I've learned some assembly, I can answer some questions.

1. `CChar` is a `C Char` ... literally. It represents the `char` type of `C`. It's a `typealias` to `Int8`. It's a single byte. You can't use this like a pointer type, as those are 8 bytes (on 64 bit machines).
2. You don't need all this `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` boilerplate, and you *certainly* don''t need to access its raw value. You can pass arrays directly where pointers are expected.

   > When a function is declared as taking an UnsafePointer argument, it can accept any of the following: ...
   >
   > - A [Type] value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array.

   from [Interacting with C APIs - pointers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID23).
3. You were experiencing issues were your mutation of `0x8(%rdi)` did not seem to be reflected on the Swift side. The issue here is that you're writing at an offset of 8 bytes, but then `print(a.load(as: void_star.self))` is reading the first byte. You're reading a byte you never modified.

I did some further exploration. Here's the loot from my adventure:

### exampleSwift.swift:

```
@_silgen_name("incrementByValue")
    func incrementByValue(_: Int64)

@_silgen_name("incrementByReference")
    func incrementByReference(_: inout Int64)

@_silgen_name("return1234")
    func return1234() -> Int64

@_silgen_name("incrementElements")
    func incrementElements(of _: UnsafeRawPointer, count _: Int)

var a: Int64 = 100
print("\"a\" before \"incrementByValue(a)\": \(a)")
incrementByValue(a)
print("\"a\" after \"incrementByValue(a)\": \(a)\n")

var b: Int64 = 200
print("\"b\" before \"incrementByValue(b)\": \(b)")
incrementByReference(&b)
print("\"b\" after \"incrementByValue(b)\": \(b)\n")

print("return1234() returned: \(return1234())\n")

var array: [Int64] = Array(0...5)

print("\"array\" before incrementElements(of: array, count: array.count): \n\t\(array)")
incrementElements(of: array, count: array.count)
print("\"array\" after incrementElements(of: array, count: array.count): \n\t\(array)\n")
```

### exampleASM.s:

```
.text

.globl _incrementByValue
.globl _incrementByReference
.globl _return1234
.globl _incrementElements

// A test routine that demonstrates operating on a value
_incrementByValue:
    // %rdi contains a copy of the argument passed in.
    // Changes here won't be reflected back in Swift
    incq %rdi
    ret

// A test routine that demonstrates operating on a reference
_incrementByReference:
    // %rdi contains a reference tp the argument passed in.
    // Changes to the reference itself won't be reflected back in Swift,
    // but changes to the referenced memory will.
    incq (%rdi)
    ret

// A test routine that demonstrates the use of %rax for returning a value
_return1234:
    movq $1234, %rax    // return value is in rax
    ret

//A test routine that demonstrates operating on an array
_incrementElements:
    // %rdi: Pointer to first of n Int64 elements
    // %rsi: the array count, n

    movq    %rsi, %rcx  // Set loop counter (%rcx) to n
    aLoop:
        incq    (%rdi)      // increment value pointer to by %rdi
        add     $8, %rdi    // advance pointer by 8 bytes
        loop    aLoop       // loop back to aLoop if rcx > 0

    ret
```

Compile, link and run with:

```
llvm-g++ -c exampleASM.s &&
swiftc -c exampleSwift.swift &&
ld exampleASM.o exampleSwift.o -o exampleBinary -force_load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a -framework CoreFoundation -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -lobjc -lSystem -arch x86_64 -L /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx -rpath /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx -no_objc_category_merging &&
./exampleBinary
```

Output:

```
"a" before "incrementByValue(a)": 100
"a" after "incrementByValue(a)": 100

"b" before "incrementByValue(b)": 200
"b" after "incrementByValue(b)": 201

return1234() returned: 1234

"array" before incrementElements(of: array, count: array.count): 
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
"array" after incrementElements(of: array, count: array.count): 
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, really appreciate it.

Comment: @jacksexton Keep in mind that none of this is set in stone until Swift achieves ABI stability. Until then, changes are possible, and likely.

Comment: I'm learning about stack/heap on Swift and fall into this question. Honestly i don't know what you guy are talking about, but I really impress with @Alexander, from what you discuss with OP to help out, while at first you didn't know much about it.. Thank you for spending your time!

Comment: @nahung89 check out [this chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127974/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-jack-sexton) for context.

Answer (score 3):

to convert MutableRawPointer to object, we use `fromOpaque` api

```
/// Unsafely turns an opaque C pointer into an unmanaged class reference.
///
/// This operation does not change reference counts.
///
///     let str: CFString = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(ptr).takeUnretainedValue()
///
/// - Parameter value: An opaque C pointer.
/// - Returns: An unmanaged class reference to `value`.
public static func fromOpaque(_ value: UnsafeRawPointer) -> Unmanaged<Instance>
```

example:

```
var info:UnsafeMutableRawPointer = ....
let obj = Unmanaged<$AnyObject>.fromOpaque(info).takeUnretainedValue()
```