# Swift3: Converting raw pointer to Int (pointer itself being the int value, doesn't point anywhere!)

Tags: c, swift, pointers, swift3

Consider the following code in C:

```
void someFunction ( int type, void * someData ) {
    unsigned value = (int)someData;
}
```

I know this code looks a bit strange but this function is a callback function and the callback function must take a `void *` argument, as very often `someData` is in fact a pointer to some memory structure (`type` would tell me which structure) but in that case it isn't. In that case it is really just an unsigned int value; not a pointer to such a value but the value itself. The caller really calls this function like this:

```
unsigned value = ...;
callbackFunction(type, (void *)value);
```

Yeah, that's stupid and ugly but I haven't written the code and I cannot change it either. I just have to implement the callback. And I would really love to do so in Swift (Swift 3). But in Swift, the callback has to look like this:

```
func someFunction ( _ type: Int, _ someData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? ) -> Void
```

And my function is called just fine... but how do I get the numeric pointer value as I need the unsigned int value and pass it on to another function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40569800/how-to-get-value-of-unsafemutablerawpointer

Comment: @Fefux If that's really a duplicate of that other question, then the answers over there are pretty poor, considering the super elegant solution MartinR has provided ;)

Comment: Yes, I posted this possible duplicate, but i read answers and they are not really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Int(bitPattern:)` to get the pointer value as an
integer:

```
func someFunction ( _ type: Int, _ someData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? ) -> Void {
    let value = Int(bitPattern: someData)
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That really works! :) You don't even need the `if let` as `bitPattern:` actually takes `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`